# Unexpected error 10548 with Pypal sandbox and NVP API. All recomendations are passed

Tags: paypal, drupal-7, paypal-sandbox, ubercart, paypal-nvp

I read this
https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1147&pmv=print&impressions=false&viewlocale=en_US

But I meet all recommedations and my sanbox merchant account does not accept payments anyway.

I enabled Business Pro for the account, the merchant's country is US, the phone is also presents but I get the error.
Please see attached screens: there are account settings, the data that I send and the data that I get.

account settings:
[image: account settings]

the values that I send:
[image: the values that I send]

the response that I get:
[image: the respons that I get]

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem. It appears to be a known issue on Paypals side.  Here is what their support told me:

> I was able to confirm your account is encountering the issue being
>   reported by several other merchants. We already have a case filed with
>   the development team to have this resolved as soon as possible. I have
>   added your account to this case so that as soon as an update or
>   resolution is provided, you will be automatically notified.

You may want to contact them (if you havent already), so you can be added to their notification:  https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/utils/login_form/

Comment: Having the same problem, in Sandbox tests, with a company account, but it did go through once, after the owner upgraded to PayPal **Pro**.  Further testing has reverted to the 10548 error, and the owner has confirmed the account is still marked PayPal Pro.

I'm tried creating my own account, a PayPal business account, but I'm not Pro and getting the same message. (You need to be Pro just to test it on the Sandbox?)  I am hesitant to pay for another Pro account when the one we have is already returning 10548 errors, with the -facilitator Sandbox API credentials on the sandbox endpoint.